# Query to get Related products sort by matching tags

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to make a related algorithm for products in a custom php site, with mysql.

I have a table for products, another for tags, and a relational one for products_tags.

Given a product, i must find products order by number of matchings tags, with the product given.

Example:

```
Product 1 tags: tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4.
Product 2 tags: tag2.
Product 3 tags: tag1, tag2, tag4.
Product 4 tags: tag1, tag5, tag2.
```

**Result:**

Product 1 related:

Product3 (3 matches)

Product4 (2 matches)

Product2 (1 match)

The idea is to do this just with one mysql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT COUNT(1) AS count1, pt1.product_id FROM product_tags pt1 WHERE
>   tag_id in (select tag_id from product_tags WHERE product_id = ?) **AND product_id != ?** GROUP
>   BY pt1.product_id ORDER BY count1 DESC

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS count1, pt1.product_id FROM product_tags pt1 WHERE tag_id in (select tag_id from product_tags WHERE product_id = ?) AND product_id != ? GROUP BY pt1.product_id ORDER BY count1 DESC
```

Altered to exclude the original product